# Add Gmail (meetup) event to Google Calendar

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, calendar, meetup

When I get an event (e.g, from `meetup.com`) email in my Gmail, I have to copy and paste it bit by bit to change it into a Google Calendar entry.

Is there an easy way (open calendar format) to move events from Gmail to Google Calendar?

Is there a simple solution with Gmail/Google Calendar app on iPhone or Android to consider for future use/purchase on a smart phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to do once you set a Meetup setting.

On [meetup.com > Settings > Email Updates](http://www.meetup.com/account/comm/), scroll down to "iCal Attachments" and check the box to "Get email reminders with iCal attachments."

Now each Meetup email announcement and confirmation will have a `meetup.ics` calendar-event attachment. Desktop Gmail and Android Gmail (I don't know about iPhone) will handle the .ics file nicely.

Desktop Gmail will display **Events in this message** at the top of the message with an **Add to Google Calendar** button.

In Android Gmail, tap on the `meetup.ics` attachment to open it in Calendar. It'll show all the meeting info with an **ADD TO CALENDAR** button at the bottom.

This should work for email from any sender as long as there's a `.ics` attachment describing the event.

**Note:** In Google Calendar, Settings > General has a setting "Events from Gmail: [x] Add automatically". Experiment with this. It does not seem to blindly add all events in Gmail messages.